# clip multiple polygons from a polygon using geopandas: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_file'

Tags: python, geopandas

I am trying to clip 600 polygon shapefiles from a bigger polygon.

The following code is to clip one shapefile from another one. How can I modify this code to first read the 600 shapefiles and then clip them from the bigger polygon?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

aoi = geopandas.read_file("C:/shp1/poly1.shp")
border = geopandas.read_file("C:/shp2/poly2.shp")

clipped = geopandas.clip(border, aoi)
outfile=clipped.to_file("C:/output/clipped.shp")
```

---

update:

I updated the code according to [page1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394527/iterating-clipping-process-through-list-of-geodataframes) and [page2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394542/save-geodataframes-from-list-to-separate-shapefiles). I tested the updated code to first clip two shapefiles. It successfully read the shapefiles and clip the regions. Once I want to save the shapefiles to separate polygons in my drive, I receive error. Here is the updated code and the error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import glob,os
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

#read the boundary
boundary = geopandas.read_file("C:/shp1/FIN_adm1.shp")

#read the two shapefiles to list
shapefiles = glob.iglob('C:/shp2/*.shp')
gdfs = [gpd.read_file(file) for file in shapefiles]

#clip the shapefiles
clipped = [gpd.clip(s, boundary) for s in gdfs]

#create a name list for two shapefiles
from natsort import natsorted
path='C:/shp2'
shp_list=[]

def getFiles(path):
    for file in natsorted(os.listdir(path)):
        if file.endswith(".shp"):
            shp_list.append(file) 

getFiles(path)
print(shp_list)

['n1.shp', 'n2.shp']

#folder for saving individual shapefiles
outfolder = 'C:/outfolder'

   #save the clipped polygons to drive 
for clipped, name in zip(clipped, shp_list):
    clipped.to_file(os.path.join(outfolder, name))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-f697ef2b1fe0> in <module>
      1 for clipped, name in zip(clipped, shp_list):
----> 2     clipped.to_file(os.path.join(outfolder, name))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_file'
```

Comment: You are reusing the name `clipped` in your loop.  That's not smart.  You're sure that `gpd.clip` returns an object that supports `to_file`?

Answer (score 0):

You just read and apply them one by one.  I assume you have some way to generate the file names.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

border = geopandas.read_file("C:/shp1/border.shp")
for i in range(600):
    aoi = geopandas.read_file("C:/shp{i+1}/poly{i+1}.shp")
    border = geopandas.clip(border, aoi)

outfile=border.to_file("C:/output/clipped.shp")
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. it returns error: No such file or directory. I updated the question with new code. Now, I have a problem to save shapefiles to separate polygons in my drive.

Comment: Restarting the kernel in jupyter lab helped to get the outputs from updated code.